# Multiple subscriptions via subscriber pool

Tags: ros, multiple, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a look at the [overview](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers) of subscribing but nothing is mentioned about short cutting via having a subscriber pool. Then initialize the subscribers inside one `for-loop`, which makes the code for multiple subscriptions shorter. 
 So instead of the conventional way:

```
ros::NodeHandle nh_;
ros::Subscriber sub_acc = nh_.subscribe(strings[1], 300, callbFloat64);
ros::Subscriber sub_mag = nh_.subscribe(strings[2], 300, callbFloat64);
ros::Subscriber sub_gyro = nh_.subscribe(strings[4], 300, callbFloat64);
ros::Subscriber sub_prox = nh_.subscribe(strings[8], 300, callbFloat64);
```

I thought of declaring a pool which gets initializied inside one loop. And it does sound good :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226805/multiple-subscriptions-via-subscriber-pool/) by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on ROS Answers with karma: 748 on 2016-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually this works, also not sure I the right way to do it.

```
ros::Subscriber spool [20];
    string strings[20] =             //string storage
    {
    [0] = "topic_0",
    [1] = "topic_1",
    [2] = "topic_2",
    [3] = "topic_3",
    ...
    }
    ros::NodeHandle nh_;

    for(int i = 0; i<20; i++){
        spool[i] = nh_.subscribe(strings[i], 300, callback);
    }
   //dedicated spinner thread, could also simply be: while(ros::ok()) ros::spin();
   tpool[pool++] = boost::thread(spinner);
```

---

Originally posted by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) with karma: 748 on 2016-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-17**:
It'll probably work. Unless you have very specific needs, I'd use something like a [MultiThreadedSpinner](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning) instead of all the boost `thread`s. The `Subscriber` 'pool' just saves a few local variables.

**Comment by [user23fj239](https://answers.ros.org/users/25791/user23fj239/) on 2016-02-17**:
Indeed, but the info on how to start the thread is not to extended and I could not implement it   ´ros::MultiThreadedSpinner spinner(4); // Use 4 threads
spinner.spin(); // spin() will not return until the node has been shutdown´

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-17**:
I'm a bit unsure about what you mean. `MultiThreadedSpinner.spin()` is basically `ros::spin()` but with the multithreaded spinner. It blocks. If you don't want to block, use `AsyncSpinner`. Documentation on the same wiki page.